# Run Hello world from node.js command prompt in windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, command-prompt

I have installed  node-v0.10.13-x86.msi    from  [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/)
    I have a file test.js having path (d:\BNB\test.js)

**test.js**:

```
console.log("Hello world!");
```

I am able to run test.js from my cmd but not from node.js command prompt refer below screenshot

From start > run > cmd (working)

[image]

From Node.exe (not working)
[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like your running the file from different locations in each console windows. Are you sure that the location is correct in the bottom screenshot?

Comment: @Sean: when i clickd node.exe it will open node.js cmd prompt and i just gave the path of my js file which is in d drive

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Node.exe is application that can be used to run code from file, or to be ran by it self that way it will behave like live-terminal.
Once you run node.exe like you did in second example, you will end up in node environment and everything from there is not cmd at all, but JS.

If you type: `node example.js` that will call node environment and will execute file in that environment.

Although, running node.exe is the same as typing `node` in cmd.

Comment: thanks for reply, I typed node `test.js` in node.exe but still its not working for me

Comment: If you already in `node.exe` you are in JS environment, and everything you will type there, will execute it in JavaScript, not CMD.
In order to execute your test.js, open `cmd.exe` and type there: `node test.js` - that is the way to run node from files.

Answer (score 5):

in node REPL you could type

```
require('d:\\BNB\\test')
```

that shuold run your file..

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to execute the program from the node prompt. You don't do that. You just run the node terminal. It sets up a bunch of variables for you. Just run it like you do in the ordinary windows shell.

Comment: Thanks for ur prompt reply, ok you mean to say i have to do like what i did in my 1st screenshot img

Comment: yeah. but in the node terminal. when you type 'node' and hit enter, you are in the wrong place, and you will get a '>' instead of your current directory. perhaps someone else can explain it better

Answer (score 3):

We can however run tests on the command prompt once we have node.js installed.

On the Windows command prompt type ***node*** *ENTER*

Then we can run our JavaScript code tests just like we do on any other Console:

*console.log("Hello World!");*

It replies with "*Hello World!*"

Answer (score 1):

To show the correct directory in Node.js you need to create the right path in your System:
System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Enviroment Variables

Then in the System variables check for Variable Path.After you have installed the Node.js it should also have :(other paths); C:\Program Files\nodejs\  <-the link of Node.js directory

Click -OK-

Now if you open Command Prompt, and you go to the directory of your .js file, the 'node' (node file.js) command should work.These steps worked to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

i believe u need to start node server from the location where your file is.